# GetBitmap from ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I know this question was asked a lot before but every time I try to retrieve the Bitmap from my ImageView it return null object

I tried :

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

And

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

And also with glide.

Am I missing something or is there another way to achieve this ?

Thanks for help

Comment: are you sure that your imageView is not null

Comment: I'm sure I logged everything. I used glide to pass drawable into my imageView before

Comment: do you need to inflate a `Bitmap` inside the `ImageView`?

Comment: yes with glide and then retrieve it

Comment: follow this tutorial https://www.11zon.com/zon/android/using-glide-to-load-bitmap-into-imageview.php if is not working, the problem is maybe the backend that gives you back a null?

Comment: I already done this but thanks anyway. I started a new project which is almost empty so nothing should be disrupt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, hope it helps

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap b = bd.getBitmap();
```

Comment: still get null object

Comment: If you breakpoint, evaluate expression an execute imageView.getDrawable() is still null? If positive, your imageview is not setting your image properly, maybe a race condition on your code is trying to reach the drawable before it is actually set.

Comment: i solved this thanks to your comment. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I have a kotlin solution.

```
val bitmap = binding.myImageView.getDrawable().toBitmap()
```

I hope that it has been useful.